Superscript and subscript labels on correlation matrix using ggcorrplot
I am trying to customize the labels on a correlation matrix made using the ggcorrplot package. However, I cannot get the superscript or subscript formatting to work. How can I get the labels to display properly without using Unicode characters?
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)

# Example Data
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:3,1:3]

# Attempt 1: Not formatted correctly
colnames(M) <- c("Temperature\n (^o C)", "PO[4]^2", "Oxygen\n (mg L^-1)")
rownames(M) <- c("Temperature\n (^o C)", "PO[4]^2", "Oxygen\n (mg L^-1)")

ggcorrplot(M,
           type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE,
           ggtheme = theme_bw())



# Attempt 2: Produces error message
ggcorrplot(M,
           type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE,
           scale_x_discrete(labels = c("mpg" = expression(Temperature~(degree*C)),
                                       "cyl" = expression(PO[4]^2),
                                       "disp" = expression(Oxygen~(mg~L^-1)))),
           scale_y_discrete(labels = c("mpg" = expression(Temperature~(degree*C)),
                                       "cyl" = expression(PO[4]^2),
                                       "disp" = expression(Oxygen~(mg~L^-1)))),
           ggtheme = theme_bw())
#> Error in match.arg(method): 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

An option with ggtext using markdown formatting:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(ggtext)

M <- cor(mtcars)[1:3,1:3]

colnames(M) <- c("Temperature<br> (<sup>o</sup> C)", "PO<sub>4</sub><sup>2</sup>", "Oxygen<br> (mg L<sup>-1</sup>)")
rownames(M) <- c("Temperature<br> (<sup>o</sup> C)", "PO<sub>4</sub><sup>2</sup>", "Oxygen<br> (mg L<sup>-1</sup>)")

ggcorrplot(M,
           type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE,
           ggtheme = theme_bw()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_markdown())


Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

this is helpful but note that the \n is meant to wrap the label onto a new line which does not appear to happening with the markdown approach.

Apologies, missed that. Updated for the line breaks with <br>.

And in case you want to stick with plotmath you can achieve your desired result via scale_x/y_discrete using scales::label_parse like so:
library(ggcorrplot)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(scales)

# Example Data
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:3, 1:3]

# Attempt 1: Not formatted correctly
colnames(M) <- rownames(M) <- c("Temperature~(degree*C)", "PO[4]^2", "Oxygen~(mg~L^-1)")

ggcorrplot(M,
  type = "lower",
  lab = TRUE,
  ggtheme = theme_bw()
) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse()) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())


One of the downsides of plotmath is that it does not support new lines. But you can fake one using atop():
colnames(M) <- rownames(M) <- c(
  "atop(Temperature, (degree*C))", "PO[4]^2",
  "atop(Oxygen, (mg~L^-1))"
)

ggcorrplot(M,
  type = "lower",
  lab = TRUE,
  ggtheme = theme_bw()
) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse()) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())


